# How to navigate to and display SwiftUI struct by id

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I managed to display images along with text from my server into a ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
   init() {
            Webservice().getAllPosts {
                print($0)
            }
        }

    @ObservedObject var model = PostListViewModel()

        var body: some View {

            List(model.posts) { post in

                 VStack{
                    Text("Title: ").bold()
                        + Text("\(post.title)")

                    ImageView(withURL: "http://localhost:8000/\(post.path.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))")

                        Text("Description: ").bold()
                        + Text("\(post.description)")


                }
            }

        }
}
```

While the data I get back looks like this:

```
[Test.Post(id: "9ffb2c83-45ed-4198-b6ab-9a259ef91b44", title: "The burbz", path: "public/1584106997200-astronomy-space-abstract-galaxy.jpg", description: "theone23"), Test.Post(id: "922f6ffc-8738-4bc2-a96d-654678540f5a", title: "Test", path: "public/1584045867007-71188186_249463072641040_8764351972645011456_n.jpg", description: "PLus that"), Test.Post(id: "45ef0279-6179-43b3-8a45-7a0fb4acefd5", title: "The burbz", path: "public/1584040897839-smiley.png", description: "OCtober"), Test.Post(id: "fa3d34ed-325b-479e-8b8f-c59831f0790d", title: "The burbz", path: "public/1584040654626-home-icon.jpg", description: "theone23"), Test.Post(id: "7c35e1ee-28e0-4845-bd14-dcad27025b04", title: "The burbz", path: "public/1584039156755-add.png", description: "theon23"), Test.Post(id: "f1567e48-eb24-4ccc-b24d-6c7c9c99e326", title: "dff", path: "public/1584038265741-Profile-img-icon.png", description: "YETT"),...
```

**Here's how I get the data:**

Fetch the data from my url

```
class Webservice {
    func getAllPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/albums")
     else {
     fatalError("URL is not correct!")
    }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

            let posts = try!

                JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!); DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(posts)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Variables

```
struct Post: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {

    let id: String
    let title: String
    let path: String
    let description: String
}
```

**Set the variables to posts from completion(posts)**

```
final class PostListViewModel: ObservableObject {

    init() {
        fetchPosts()
    }

    @Published var posts = [Post]()

    private func fetchPosts() {
        Webservice().getAllPosts {
            self.posts = $0
        }
    }


}
```

My question is how click on an item from List by id or whatever I could do to Navigate to and view each item from the list by id and display all the contents by id.

Comment: Wrap your `List` into `NavigationView` and use `NavigationLink` inside with your `VStack` as label... there are huge amount of examples here - just search by keywords.

Comment: Okay I did it by using this example here: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

Answer (score 0):

I followed the information from Apple on how to building lists with navigation here:
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation and it worked. Thanks Apple.